# qml js library vs member function: Cannot call method 'destroy' of null

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

What is the difference between function in pure JavaScript library (marked with ".pragma library")
and member function in QML in context of my code?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "."

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow

    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    function showDialog(params) {
        const comp = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyPopup.qml");
        const err = comp.errorString();
        if (err)
            console.log("MyPopup component loading failed:", err);

        const dlg = comp.createObject(params.parent, params);
        console.assert(dlg !== null, "MyPopup object creation failed");
        console.log("opening");
        dlg.open();
    }

    Button {
        text: "Press me"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("you press button");

            const params = {parent: applicationWindow.contentItem};
            //applicationWindow.showDialog(params); // !!! 1
            CreateDialog.showDialog2(params); // !!! 2
        }
    }
}
```

and my popup window:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Popup {
    id: view

    width: 300
    height: 300
    onClosed: {
        console.log("onClosed was called", view);
        view.destroy();
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Popup!!!"
    }
}
```

If I use variant (1) all works fine if I open Popup and then press "Alt+F4" (on Windows) or "Command+Q" on macOS.

But if I move 'showDialog' into 'CreateDialog.js' file and add '.pragma library' at the top of it,
then during exit from application with open Popup I got:

```
qrc:/MyPopup.qml:11: TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of null
```

so Qt/QML runtime call signal of dead object.
What is going on, is reference to dialog "hanging" somewhere in "pure javascript" case,
and so Qt can not destroy it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By default, JavaScript files imported from QML share their context with the QML component.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#shared-javascript-resources-libraries) If you remove the `.pragma library` from your JS file, the code behaves the same as if the JS code is run in your main QML file because they share the same context. So, why does `.pragma library` affect this? `.pragma library` creates a singleton-like JS file, and because any QML file can access it, its context is generically set to the [root context](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#rootContext) or some top-level orphan context (not sure, could not determine from docs), not the context of the file that calls it.

From context documentation:

> While QML objects instantiated in a context are not strictly owned by
> that context, their bindings are. If a context is destroyed, the
> property bindings of outstanding QML objects will stop evaluating.

I believe what you are seeing is the opposite of the second sentence, where the root context owns the bindings of your popup, and is calling its `onClosed` signal after its destruction.

So, your two scenarios described:

**First Scenario:**

1. Popup created, assigned `applicationWindow` parent, its creation context matches `applicationWindow`
2. Window closed, `applicationWindow` destruction starts
3. Because popup is child of `applicationWindow`, it is destroyed
4. `applicationWindow` context is destroyed, bindings stop being evaluated
5. popup closed signal is not called because its creation context was destroyed, no error thrown

**Second Scenario:**

1. Popup created, assigned `applicationWindow` parent, BUT its creation context is the root context
2. Window closed, `applicationWindow` destruction starts
3. Because popup is child of `applicationWindow`, it is destroyed
4. `applicationWindow` context is destroyed
5. after `applicationWindow` destruction, popup closed signal is called because its (root) creation context still exists, error is thrown because references in the signal handler have been destroyed

Probably the best way to solve this is to not use `.pramga library` in JS files that manage object creation. Otherwise, it is not a particularly worrisome error as it is smart enough to know the reference has been destroyed and doesn't access freed memory. You can get rid of the error by checking `if (view)` before calling `view.destroy()`